# Join 2 tables with different columns

Tags: mysql

Bank Database Schema:

```
account    (account_number, branch_name, balance) 
branch     (branch_name, branch_city, assets) 
customer   (customer_name customer_street, customer_city) 
loan       (loan_number, branch_name, amount) 
deposito   (customer_name, account_number) 
borrower   (customer_name, loan_number)
```

**how do i knw the account_number of borrowers????**

Comment: Is that your full table structure?  How do you know what `account_number` goes with each `customer_name`?

Comment: Does table 2 have a link to table 1 e.g. table2.account_number?

Comment: table 2 has no link to table 1.

Comment: Bank Database Schema:

account(account_number, branch_name, balance)

branch (branch_name, branch_city, assets)

customer (customer_name customer_street, customer_city)

loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount) 

depositor((customer_name, account_number)

borrower(customer_name, loan_number)

this is the original database....
how do i knw the account_number of borrowers????

Comment: @NamanKhator Please add this in your question, so that you got good answers. Why you didn't post that in your question first time? How can we know that??????

Comment: **sorry** for the inconvenience....

Comment: **THANK YOU EVERY ONE, SOLVED IT**

Answer (score 5):

try this.. (according to your comment)

```
SELECT c.customer_name,
  a.account_number
FROM customer c
  INNER JOIN depositor d
    ON c.customer_name = d.customer_name
  INNER JOIN borrower b
    ON d.customer_name = b.customer_name
  INNER JOIN account a
    ON a.account_number = d.account_number
```

See [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a8e/3)

UPDATE:

```
SELECT b.customer_name,
  d.account_number
FROM borrower b
  INNER JOIN depositor d
    ON d.customer_name = b.customer_name
  INNER JOIN account a
ON a.account_number = d.account_number
```

See [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f874/3)

Comment: if u add a customer and he is just a borrower _not_ a depositor it doesn't work :(

Comment: @NamanKhator check my updated answer. It gives all borrowers and their account numbers

Comment: but what about e, f, g, h if one of them takes only loan then i cant get their account numbers :(

Comment: **THANK YOU EVERY ONE, SOLVED IT**

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, it looks like the `customers` are related to the `accounts` via the `depositor` table. If so, then you can use:

```
select c.customer_name,
  a.account_number,
  a.balance
from customer c
inner join depositor d
  on c.customer_name = d.customer_name
inner join account a
  on d.account_number = a.account_number
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/404c9/1)

If you want to know the account number of the borrowers, then you will add a JOIN to the `borrower` table:

```
select c.customer_name,
  a.account_number,
  a.balance
from customer c
inner join depositor d
  on c.customer_name = d.customer_name
inner join account a
  on d.account_number = a.account_number
inner join borrower b
  on c.customer_name = b.customer_name
```

It seems to that your database design has a few issues with it. Based on your current structure if you want to know the `borrowers`, then you have to join on either the `depositor` to get the account number or the `loan` table to associate a loan to an account.

If you join on the `loan` table the query will be:

```
select b.customer_name,
  a.account_number
from borrowers b
inner join loan l
  on b.loan_number = l.loan_number
inner join account a
  on l.branch_number = a.branch_number
```

But the issue is that the `loan` table can join to `account` only on `branch_number`, this branch number will be associated with multiple accounts.  You should have a column that will identify the `borrower` with each `loan`, since this is missing you currently have no way to find the account number for each borrower.

Comment: i need the borrowers and their account_number

Comment: if i would have wanted the depositors i would have just written : 


`select customer_name,account_number,balance from depositor natural join account;`

Comment: @NamanKhator When posting a question you should be specific in what you  want as a result.

Comment: If you want borrowers instead of depositors, it's a very simple modification.  If you can't figure out this much of it, please consult a basic book on SQL.

Comment: @NamanKhator See my edit, if you want the borrower details, then you will want to join on that table as well

Comment: if u add a customer and he is just a borrower not a depositor it doesn't work :(

Comment: @NamanKhator My suggestion would be to edit your original post with data from each table and explain the desired result that you want. At this point we would be guessing how to solve this.

Comment: @NamanKhator See my edit, the only way you can get to the account number for borrowers is through the loan but it looks like you have a one-to-many relationship and this will alter the result.  You need to reconsider your current design.

Comment: `create view t1 as (select account_number,balance from account where account_number not in (select account_number from depositor));`

Comment: `create view t2 as (select customer_name from borrower);`

Comment: `create table naman select * from (select t.account_number,t.balance, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum from (select account_number,balance from t1 ) t, (select @rownum:=0) r ) as z;`
`create table naman1 select * from (select tt.customer_name, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum from (select customer_name from t2 ) tt, (select @rownum:=0) r ) as x;`
`create view borrower_account as (select customer_name,account_number,balance from naman1 natural join naman);`
`select * from borrower_acount;`

Comment: @NamanKhator Comments are for clarification and some discussion, not for posting code or details that should be on your question. Also, this answer was fine for your original question, and the modified one that you asked on comments and another time when you add more requirements. Either you stop and write a **full**, complete question or your post might be closed as "Not a Real Question", since it's almost impossible to understand what you are asking

Comment: **THANK YOU EVERY ONE, SOLVED IT**

Comment: sorry it was my first time i didn't had ny idea of how to ask or how to convey the question.... _SORRY PLEASE_